# How to calculate an elliptic integral involving complexes using GSL?

Tags: gsl

I need to calculate

```
∫ [x₁ to x₂] 1/√(1-k² sinh²(x)) dx
```

in my program. This can be expressed using the incomplete elliptic integral of the first kind evaluated in a *complex* argument:

```
-i (F(ix₂ | -k²) - F(ix₁ | -k²)).
```

I found that GSL provides the elliptic integral F but it does not seem to be overloaded for complexes. Is there some extension available for this or a different library I could use instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, this was a rushed question. But in case someone might be interested in the same in the future, perhaps a self-answer will be helpful.

Looking at GSL's source code, I found that F(φ,k) is reduced (as long as φ ∈ [-π,π]) to

```
sin(φ) RF(1-sin²(φ), 1-k²sin²(φ), 1),
```

where RF is another GSL function. There's no F(iφ,k) but we can safely plug a pure imaginary φ in the above as all the three arguments stay real:

```
sin(iφ) = i sinh(φ)
=>
F(iφ,k) = sin(iφ) RF(1+sinh²(φ), 1+k²sinh²(φ), 1)
=>
-i F(iφ | -k^2) = sinh(φ) RF(1+sinh²(φ), 1-k²sinh²(φ), 1)
```

Comment: You can answer your own questions, that is a good thing. Just remember to tick the flag.

Comment: @Francesco Thank you for the edit and the info! I "accepted" my own answer now, is that what you meant?